# A set of paragraphs of 4 lines to manage with AWK

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file composed of several paragraphs (more than 2000) of 4 lines.
For each paragraph, I need to match the content between brackets like the example below.

So for each paragraph,

- the entries are the first two lines.
- for the third line, the current content between the brackets is replaced by the content between the second line brackets.
- for the fourth line, the current content between the brackets is replaced by the content between the first line brackets.

I hope it's clear enough.

--Inputs--

```
A1 [A3 A4 A5] A2
B1 [B3 B4 B5] B2
C1 [C3 C4] C2
D1 [D3 D4] D2

E1 [E3 E4 E5] E2
F1 [F3 F4 F5] F2
G1 [G3 G4] G2
H1 [H3 H4] H2
```

--Outputs--

```
A1 [A3 A4 A5] A2
B1 [B3 B4 B5] B2
C1 [B3 B4 B5] C2
D1 [A3 A4 A5] D2

E1 [E3 E4 E5] E2
F1 [F3 F4 F5] F2
G1 [F3 F4 F5] G2
H1 [E3 E4 E5] H2
```

Do you have a solution? With awk and gsub I guess but how it's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk -F[][] -vOFS= '++i==1 {a=$2} i==2 {b=$2} i==3 {$2="[" b "]"} i==4 {$2="[" a "]"} !NF {i=0} 1' input.txt
```

With square brackets as the field separators, your replacement sources/targets are in `$2`.

We increment `i` on each line, and reset it to zero between paragraphs.  The value of `i` (1 though 4) tells us what to do with `$2`.

Comment: If there is no space between paragraphs, how your code should be modified ?

Comment: if no space, change `!NF {i=0}` to `{i%=4}`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/\[.*]/) {
    idx = (NR - 1) % 5 + 1
    sect[idx] = substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    if ( idx == 3 ) {
        $0 = $1 OFS sect[2] OFS $NF
    }
    else if ( idx == 4 ) {
        $0 = $1 OFS sect[1] OFS $NF
    }
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
A1 [A3 A4 A5] A2
B1 [B3 B4 B5] B2
C1 [B3 B4 B5] C2
D1 [A3 A4 A5] D2

E1 [E3 E4 E5] E2
F1 [F3 F4 F5] F2
G1 [F3 F4 F5] G2
H1 [E3 E4 E5] H2
```

The above does string replacement so it'll work even if the sections inside brackets contain regexp metachars or backreferences.

Answer (score 1):

GNU awk, assuming that there are no regex-special characters between the brackets:

```
$ gawk -vRS= '
  BEGIN{OFS=FS="\n"}
  match($1,/\[[^]]*\]/,x) && match($2,/\[[^]]*\]/,y) {
    sub(/\[[^]]*\]/,y[0],$3);
    sub(/\[[^]]*\]/,x[0],$4);
    printf "%s%s", $0, RT
  }
  ' file
A1 [A3 A4 A5] A2
B1 [B3 B4 B5] B2
C1 [B3 B4 B5] C2
D1 [A3 A4 A5] D2

E1 [E3 E4 E5] E2
F1 [F3 F4 F5] F2
G1 [F3 F4 F5] G2
H1 [E3 E4 E5] H2
```

The same is essentially do-able in non-GNU awk except you will need to use `substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)` etc. to obtain the replacements, and you won't be able to use `RT` to restore the original input record separators:

```
awk '
  BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; OFS=FS="\n"}
  match($1,/\[[^]]*\]/) {x = substr($1,RSTART,RLENGTH)}
  match($2,/\[[^]]*\]/) {y = substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)}
  {
    sub(/\[[^]]*\]/,y,$3);
    sub(/\[[^]]*\]/,x,$4);
    print
  }
  ' file
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but my computer doesn't manage gawk. Is it possible for you to describe your idea with awk ?

Comment: @titofpoule please see updated answer

Comment: Which code modification must I make if I have no empty lines between paragraphs ?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -n -E '
    1~5 { p; s/.*(\[.*\]).*/\1/;h };
    2~5 { p; s/.*(\[.*\]).*/\1/;
          N; s/\n//; s/^(\[.*?\])([^[]*)\[.*\]/\2\1/;p;x;
          N; s/\n//; s/^(\[.*?\])([^[]*)\[.*\]/\2\1/;p;
}; 5~5p'  infile
```

---

**TL;DR**

`1~5 { ... }`: this applies on every 5<sup>th</sup> lines start from the first line; and same
`2~5 { ... }`: applies on every 5<sup>th</sup> lines but start from the second line; and
`5~5 p`: applies on every 5<sup>th</sup> lines start from the fifth line;

breaking each command down:

- `1~5 { p; s/.*(\[.*\]).*/\1/;h }`:

  - the `p` command: prints the entire line that matched `1~5` condition, so for the first paragraph first line read and will go to output without change; output now is:

    ```
    A1 [A3 A4 A5] A2
    ```
  - with `s/.*(\[.*\]).*/\1/`, we captures `[ ... ]` part only from that line and remove everything else from the output; then
  - with `h` command we copy that result into **h**old-space; so now hold-space contains this `[A3 A4 A5]`.
- `2~5 { p; s/.*(\[.*\]).*/\1/;`:

  - the `p` command: almost same as the above, but this is for every 5<sup>th</sup> lines number starting from the second line as said; so it will print second line; now output is:

    ```
    A1 [A3 A4 A5] A2
    B1 [B3 B4 B5] B2
    ```
  - with `s/.*(\[.*\]).*/\1/`, we again capture the `[ ... ]` part from the second line, and remove everything else and do nothing; now our pattern-space contains this `[B3 B4 B5]` (and reminder that hold-space is still not changed and that is `[A3 A4 A5]`)
  - in `N; s/\n//; s/^(\[.*?\])([^[]*)\[.*\]/\2\1/; p; x;`

    - `N`, read the next line (3<sup>rd</sup> line now) and append it into pattern-space with embedded newline between; so now our pattern-space changed as following:

      ```
      [B3 B4 B5]
      C1 [C3 C4] C2
      ```
    - with `s/\n//;` we delete that embedded newline first; now we have below in pattern-space

      ```
      [B3 B4 B5]C1 [C3 C4] C2
      ```
    - in `s/^(\[.*?\])([^[]*)\[.*\]/\2\1/; p; x;`:
    - with `^(\[.*?\])`, we capture `[B3 B4 B5]` part with back-reference of `\1` that is beginning of line
    - with `([^[]*)`, captures `C1`  part with back-reference of `\2`
    - with `\[.*\]`, captures `[C3 C4]` part, but will remove from the line
    - in replacement part `\2\1` will preserve only, so now pattern-space is:

      ```
      C1 [B3 B4 B5] C2
      ```
    - next command is `p`, OK, print it; now output is:

      ```
      A1 [A3 A4 A5] A2
      B1 [B3 B4 B5] B2
      C1 [B3 B4 B5] C2
      ```
    - now pattern-space is `C1 [B3 B4 B5] C2` and hold-space is still `[A3 A4 A5]`; and
    - with the next command `x`, we exchange the pattern-space with hold-space; now pattern-space is `[A3 A4 A5]`; and hold-space we don't need it and leave it for now.
  - in `N; s/\n//; s/^(\[.*?\])([^[]*)\[.*\]/\2\1/; p;`:

    - `N`, read the next line (4<sup>th</sup> line now) and append it into pattern-space with embedded newline between; so now our pattern-space changed as following:

      ```
      [A3 A4 A5]
      D1 [D3 D4] D2
      ```
    - in `s/\n//;` we delete that embedded newline first; now we have below in pattern-space

      ```
      [A3 A4 A5]D1 [D3 D4] D2
      ```
    - with `s/^(\[.*?\])([^[]*)\[.*\]/\2\1/; p;`:
    - with `^(\[.*?\])`, we capture `[A3 A4 A5]` part with back-reference of `\1` that is beginning of line
    - with `([^[]*)`, captures `D1`  part with back-reference of `\2`
    - with `\[.*\]`, captures `[D3 D4]` part, but will remove from the line
    - in replacement part `\2\1` will preserve only, so now pattern-space is:

      ```
      D1 [A3 A4 A5] D2
      ```
    - next command is `p`, OK, print it; now output is:

      ```
      A1 [A3 A4 A5] A2
      B1 [B3 B4 B5] B2
      C1 [B3 B4 B5] C2
      D1 [A3 A4 A5] D2
      ```
- with `5~5p` we print every 5<sup>th</sup> line start from line 5, that is empty line between each paragraph.
  now first paragraph procced and the same steps will continue by the `sed` until all lines read and proceed.

Comment: +1 As a fellow sed fan I thank you for the effort you put in this answer. I didn't tested it yet, but I understood the approach and parts of the code already.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -00pe 's/(.*)(\[.*\])(.*\n)
              (.*)(\[.*\])(.*\n)
              (.*)(\[.*\])(.*\n)
              (.*)(\[.*\])(.*\n)
             /$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$5$9$10$2$12/x' input1
```

`perl -00pe` -- for each paragraph.

Each line of the RE matches an input paragraph line and separates it in the relevant parts.
In the substitution group we
just have to reorder the parts.

Sorry for the obfuscation...

Comment: `$8` and `$11` don't need to be captured.  `$12` doesn't need to be in the regex at all.  `/s` shortens the regex by allowing `.` to match newlines:  `perl -00pe 's/(.*) (\[.*\]) (.*) (\[.*\]) (.*) \[.*\] (.*) \[.*\] /$1$2$3$4$5$4$6$2/sx' in.txt`

Comment: @OhMyGoodness, thank you. You are right. (we can reduce even more) I just put 12 groups to have vertical analogies -- (and arguably be more readble)

Answer (score 0):

And also with GNU `awk` for the 3rd argument to `match()` and using a second array indexed with `NR` and the default settings for `RS` and `FS`:

Updated:

```
awk  '
{
    match($0, /([^\[]*)(\[.*\])([^\]]*)/,a)
    b[NR]=a[2]
    if (NR==3){print a[1], b[NR-1],a[3];next}
    if (NR==4){print a[1], b[NR-3],a[3];next}
    else {print a[1], a[2], a[3]}
    if ($0 == "") {NR=0}
}' file
A1  [A3 A4 A5]  A2
B1  [B3 B4 B5]  B2
C1  [B3 B4 B5]  C2
D1  [A3 A4 A5]  D2

E1  [E3 E4 E5]  E2
F1  [F3 F4 F5]  F2
G1  [F3 F4 F5]  G2
H1  [E3 E4 E5]  H2
```

Comment: This is a good start/proof of concept, but with the hard-coded field values, it's not useful in a real world context.

Comment: Ok, @Joe. Perhaps putting the focus in the 'NR` it's more usefull. I've updated the code.

Comment: I was surprised that you can assign a value to NR and still have it work. Since NR is a special variable, that's not a good practice even if it works. Your revision is a big improvement otherwise. When someone else views your code or you do after some time, any unexpected behavior like that can lead to errors. In a simple piece of code like this, it's not that much of an issue, but in something more complex it could be serious.

Comment: After reading your comment, I've been looking for in the web, in the manual and in the info awk. Looking for in "info gawk" (`info gawk | awk '/NR/'`), in the apart "Changing 'NR' and 'FNR'", there is a simple example programm , whith this line showing this assignation: `awk 'NR == 2 { NR = 17 }`. So I think the code is correct. Thanks for your opinion about this code. Regards.